# Is it legal for a RESTful API to provide different structures for a given resource? How should that be modeled?

Tags: rest, api-design, swagger

I'm using swagger to prototype a RESTful API and I got to a situation where one property is part of a resource but not always should be filled.

Let's say my resource is `stores`.

Basic endpoints would be:

`GET: /stores` - returns a list of `store`

`GET: /stores/{storeId}` - returns a single `store`

Say store is defined along the lines of:

```
Store {
  id: integer,
  name: string,
  pictures: array[]
}
```

But when returning the list of stores, also returning every store's list of pictures is overkill. Pictures should be only returned for a single store request.

I'm confused on how to model that situation. On swagger, both methods responses are associated with a `store` object.

Should I split `store` into two objects and definitions so that each method return a different type even though only one property is different?

Should I use a query string parameter so that the consumer can choose whether or not pictures should be filled? Something along the lines of:

`GET: /stores?fillPictures=false` or maybe

`GET: /stores?detailed=false`

When choosing the second option, the definition of a single `store` would be the same no matter which endpoint is being accessed. That would mean an empty property would be transmitted to the consumer for every non detailed (with pictures) request. Should that be a concern?

Can someone shed some light on how to handle this scenario in a RESTful way? Maybe you know some API with a similar operation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would the `pictures` array contain actual picture data or links where the pictures can be obtained when needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> GET: /stores - returns a list of store
>
> GET: /stores/{storeId} - returns a single store

These are two different resources (a store, and a list of stores), so it is fine that they have different data.

The resource representing a list of stores can contain just enough information for the client to navigate to the store it might want. So it might be something like

```
Request
    GET /stores

Response
  200 - OK

  {
    stores: [
      {id: 34, name: "Walmart", url: "/stores/34"},
      {id: 35, name: "Best Buy", url: "/stores/35"}
    ]
  }
```

The client can then navigate to the individual store to get any further information it needs about a particular store.

Comment: You can calibrate this to precisely meet your needs: `/stores` could include one thumbnail picture, and then `/stores/{storesId}` or `/stores/{storeId}/pictures` could provide every available picture, with that link included in your first response.

Comment: You're right. Different resources. @Gaurav what you wrote is exactly how i'm going. I was hanging too much on the fact that my swagger specification would have two very close definitions but I guess that's ok.

Comment: @RodrigoLira - I think that you've identified a key point in your comment. Do not conflate a clean swagger spec with a well designed API.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a many/many relationship (ie. a picture can go with mutiple stores) I would go with

```
Store {
  id: integer,
  name: string,
  pictureIds: array[]
}
```

and a separate endpoint

```
POST: /getPictures pictureIds: array[]
```

If its a one store per picture relationship :

```
Store {
  id: integer,
  name: string
}

POST : /getPicturesForStores  storeIds : array[]
```

Both these methods allow you to get a list of stores, and display all the pictures related to that list in two requests without duplicating data.

POST is required for 'get many' style requests as there is prohibitively small limit on the number of characters allowed in a url query string